Engine light came on my nissan note car while driving
I have an issue with my nissan note e12 car while I was driving my engine light came on I take the car to scan and the scan said  airbag error it was reset but after driving again the engine light came on back could could this be fixed?

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Is it the same code the 2nd time? What exactly is the code (ID)?
